# Decreasing sequence of non-negative integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Let $ a_n , \ n=0, 1, 2, \dots\ $ be a strictly monotonically decreasing sequence consisting of non-negative integers. The sequence also has a lower bound C such that $ a_n \ge C >-\infty.$

Intuitively, we know, that $a_n$ has to have finite amount of entries, but can this be proven exactly?

Comment: Well, we know that $a_n≥0$ for example.

Comment: As it’s non negative it is greater than or equal to zero

Comment: Mmh consider $a_n = \frac1{n}$. It doesn't reach a minimum, though its inferior limit is $0$

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is infinite then of course it can't stay non-negative.  If $\{a_n\}$ is finite then the last entry is the best lower bound.

Comment: I am hoping, that someone could proof exactly, that this sequence $$ a_n $$ is finite, and since it is strictly decreasing, the last entry is the minimum.

Comment: If $a_0$ is $M$ then the sequence can have no more than $M+1$ terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems kind of obvious, but let's do it anyway. We know three things:

1: The sequence is *strictly* decreasing, i.e, $a_{n+1}<a_n.$

2: $a_n \in \mathbb{Z} ~~\forall n.$

3: $a_n\geq 0 ~\forall n$.

Condition (1) implies that all of the terms of $a_n$ are distinct, i.e, $\nexists m,n\in\mathbb{N}:a_m=a_n$. Now using condition (2), let $a_0=N$, some positive integer. We know, using condition (1), that all subsequent terms are $<N$, and using condition (3), are all $\geq0.$  Now suppose $a_n$ had infinitely many terms. That would imply that there are infinitely many integers in the range $[0,N]$, which is clearly false. Thus $a_n$ can only have finitely many terms.